# Solve $x^n=1$ in a monoid.

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, monoid

Let $(X, *)$ a monoid with identity $e$. So can the equality
$$
x^n=e
$$
hold for some $n\ge 1$ when $x$ is not equal to $e$? If this can be true what is an example? If this is not true how prove it?

Comment: $1+1 = 0$ in $\mathbb Z_2$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Sorry my ignorance but I started to study Algebra seriously only today: what is $\Bbb Z_2$? I point out by Linear Algebra I know what is a group, what is a ring, what is a Field.

Comment: No. For example, the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ and all $x\neq0$.

Comment: Whether the equation has a solution depends on the monoid.  In some monoids, there is a solution; in others there isn't.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_2$ is the monoid where $X=\{e, a\}$ and $\ast$ is the function that has $e\ast e = a\ast a = e$ and $e\ast a = a\ast e = a$.  In this monoid $x^n=e$ has the solution $a^2 = e$.

Comment: Just take the set of all complex numbers on the unit circle: $U=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid |z|=1\}$, with ordinary multiplication. This is a monoid. (Right?) The role of $e$ is played by $1$. Do equations $z^n=1$ have solutions other than $z=1$? Now take $(0, +\infty)\subseteq \mathbb R$ ("positive real numbers") with ordinary multiplication. This is a monoid and $1$ is again in the role of $e$. Does $x^n=1$ imply $x=1$ there?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Oh, nice counterexample! Thanks really.

Comment: @MJD Thanks for informations!

Comment: @Arthur You are right: I edited the question.

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's theorem? In a finite group, if n is the number of elements, all elements of the group are solutions of $x^n = 1$.

Comment: @PseudoNeo Oh, really nice theorem!!! Well, unfortunately I did not know it before you enunciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the set of all complex numbers on the unit circle: $U=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid|z|=1\}$, with ordinary multiplication. This is a monoid. (Right?) The role of $e$ is played by $1$. Do equations $z^n=1$ have solutions other than $z=1$?

Now take $(0,+\infty)\subset\mathbb R$ ("positive real numbers") with ordinary multiplication. This is a monoid and $1$ is again in the role of $e$. Does $x^n=1$ imply $x=1$ there?

Comment: To complete the answer: into the first case I would put $z$ equal to $i$ and $n$ equal to $4$ but for the second case I suppose that only $1$ solve the equation. Anyway, thanks for the answer: I just upvoted it and if you reply to my comment adding more details about the second case (are there any other observations to add to the ones I just made?) then I surely will accept it.

Comment: In the first case you can put $z$ equal to $\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}$ and then it will work for _any_ $n$ ([De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).) In the second case, on $(0, +\infty)$ the function $x\mapsto x^n$ is _strictly_ increasing so it can have any value _at most_ once. As $1^n=1$, no other value $x$ can map to $1$.

Comment: Okay, all clear: answer approved. Thanks very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Since every abelian group is equipped with a commutative multiplication and an identity, it suffices to consider a finite abelian group. Just as Brevan has mentioned, we can consider $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, or the cyclic group of order 2 which contains the identity and only one non-trivial element $1$. Since this group is cyclic we must have $1+1=0$.